# Google license validation suddenly failing on development device

Tags: android, android-lvl

I released an app that uses Google LVL to the Market many months ago. For some reason, the app instance on my Nexus One development phone consistently fails validation, starting about 3 days ago (March 25, 2012). Customers running the same version of my app do not report any failures. I tried toggling the licensing response via my Developer console - license check still fails. I uninstalled and reinstalled the app, to no effect. (I install the app on my developer phone with adb, as Google doesn't allow me to purchase my own app through the Store). I'm wondering whether this problem is due to recent changes in the Market/Play app; the phone is running version 3.5.15 of the Play Store. Does anyone know why this might be happening, and how to fix it?
Thanks,
Tom

Comment: License validation fails, but LicenseCheckerCallback.applicationError() is never called! The call to dontAllow() is preceded by this message: "I/LicenseChecker( 4089): Check timed out." Others have seen similar behavior (e.g. http://forum.xda-developers.com/showthread.php?t=1566770) but the recommended "fix" at that link does not work for me.

Answer (score 10, accepted):

Fixed. Via "Manage apps" I stopped the Google Play Store app, cleared its data (not the cache, which was zero bytes), then restarted my licensed app - licensing now works.